# Add “album_artist” tag to an opus file

Tags: file-metadata, multimedia

I find the `opusenc` command (from the `opus-tools` package in Debian) to edit Opus files metadata.

But, according to his man’s synopsis (and other sections in the man) it doesn’t provide a way to edit album_artist tag (like `metaflac` fro flac files or `id3v` for mp3 files):

```
opusenc  [  -h  ]  [  -V ] [ --help-picture ] [ --quiet ] [ --bitrate kbit/sec ] [ --vbr ] [ --cvbr ] [ --hard-cbr ] [ --comp complexity ] [ --framesize 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 40, 60 ] [ --expect-loss pct ] [ --downmix-mono ] [ --downmix-stereo ] [ --max-delay ms ] [ --title 'track title' ] [ --artist author ] [ --album 'album title' ] [ --genre genre ]  [  --date YYYY-MM-DD  ]  [  --comment  tag=value  ] [ --picture filename|specification ] [ --padding n ] [ --discard-comments ] [ --discard-pictures ] [ --raw ] [ --raw-bits bits/sample ] [ --raw-rate Hz ] [ --raw-chan N ] [ --raw-endianness flag ] [ --ignorelength ] [ --serial serial number ] [ --save-range file ] [ --set-ctl-int ctl=value ] input.wav output.opus
```

So, simply, how to add an album_artist tag to an opus file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPUS does not support tags. At all. It is a pure encoding format designed for streaming.
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6716

For storage, opus is usually converted to ogg - it does support tags. And ogg container can have an opus file directly, so the conversion is very easy and fast.

As variant you can convert to mp3 or flac. These two will do re-coding audio stream.